# Running a series of VBScripts within an ASP.net (vb.net) page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript

I have a requirement when a user clicks a specific arrangement of radio buttons to run a series of vbscripts (and soon Perl scripts).

I have all of the vbscripts stored server side, they do not need to be on the remote system to run. Oh yes, the scripts are gathering information on remote system in our intranet.

What would be the best way. Currently I have this to run just one script, not multiple...should I keep this or dispose of this idea.

```
Protected Sub windowsScript(ByVal COMPUTERNAME As String)
    ' Create an array to store VBScript results
    Dim winVariables(1) As String
    Dim filePath As String = COMPUTERNAME & "\C$\Windows\somefile.txt"
    'Execute PsExec on script
    runPsExec(COMPUTERNAME, "systemInfo.vbs", 1)
    'Import data from text file into variables
    textRead(filePath, winVariables)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    'Delete the file on server - we don't need it anymore
    runPsExec(COMPUTERNAME, "systemInfo.vbs", 2)
    MsgBox("Windows OS: " & winVariables(0).ToString())
    MsgBox("Service Pack: " & winVariables(1).ToString())

End Sub
```

Also, it is hard to see here because I do have another function "textRead" but what is going on is this particular script is stored client side and the vbscript it outputting to a text file. textRead will read the variable and send a text file back to the server to read it.

This is definitely not what I want to do.
I want to be a little more dynamic, plus with my new scripts...they don't need to be on the client at all.

Any help would be appreciated :)

I'm thinking of making some type of While loop, not sure if that would work.

Comment: I'd use something like the [Observer pattern](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/490/observer-pattern/) to handle a case like this.

Comment: I kind of understand this pattern after reading it. I haven't needed to use any objects in my code. It has all been very procedural in my codebehind. I can't even think of a way that I would turn it into objects (Note: I am lacking a bit in OO programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of strange to do this through the browser. In my company we collect systeminfo at logontime with a vbscript logonscript and add the result to a logfile which we can access through a webapp to do research. Occasionally when the need rises we run a specific script to gather more data or change some system setting through windows SCCM.

If the goal is to provide the user with info about his system there are some good utilities around which can be run locally (but from a location on a server share).

EDIT

a simple way to start multiple processes

```
dim scripts_to_run, script
const COMPUTERNAME = 0, SCRIPTNAME = 1, EXTRA_PARAMS = 2
scripts_to_run = Array(_
  Array("computer1","script1.vbs",1),_
  Array("computer2","script1.vbs",0),_
  Array("computer3","script3.vbs",3)_
)
for each script in scripts_to_run
  runPsExec script(COMPUTERNAME), script(SCRIPTNAME), script(EXTRA_PARAMS)
  runPsExec join(script,",")
next

sub runPsExec(p1, p2, p3)
  'here coms your code shat runs the script
  wscript.echo p1 & p2 & p3
end sub
```

or a shorter version

```
dim scripts_to_run, aArgs
scripts_to_run = Array(_
  Array("computer1","script1.vbs",1),_
  Array("computer2","script1.vbs",0),_
  Array("computer3","script3.vbs",3)_
)
for each aArgs in scripts_to_run
  runPsExec aArgs
next

sub runPsExec(aArgs)
  'here coms your code shat runs the script
  wscript.echo aArgs(0) & aArgs(1) & aArgs(2)
end sub
```

Comment: I am just testing using a system info script. The actual idea is to check the configuration of a server for our build team. There will be multiple scripts.

Comment: in that case, i added a script sample thats shows you how to start multiple processes (scripts here) in an easy to configure manner. based on the manner how you call the scripts they can be executed async or sync

Comment: I like this idea a lot. So this becomes a 2-Dimensional array. What is the integer at the end? 1,0,3?

Comment: i just followed your example, it's the third parameter like 2 in **runPsExec(COMPUTERNAME, "systemInfo.vbs", 2)** it could for example be a parameter that indicates whether the motherscript should have to wait till the childscript has ended